# Transpose coordinates from pdf map onto satellite raster image

Tags: r, raster, projection

I have a map in a PDF file with boundaries that I want to plot onto a satellite image.

I have made a screenshot, saved it as tiff and imported it as a R `raster` object. Using `click` I have outlined the boundaries which I can now plot onto the raster object.

[image]

head of polygon data.frame:

```
> head(df)
       x      y value idx
1: 408.5 1041.5   135   1
2: 361.5  988.5   255   2
3: 344.5  997.5   170   3
4: 310.5  960.5   237   4
5: 312.5  950.5   237   5
6: 257.5  816.5   254   6
```

My goal is to convert the data.frame with x and y coordinates to a spatial object (sf or sp) and plot it onto a satellite image.

The problem is the projection: How do I convert my relative positions to a projection that matches that of my satellite image?

The original projection is UTM Zone 37, projection Transverse Mercator, Spheroid Clarke 1880 (modified).

(no answers on the [GIS stackexchange site](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/341309/transposing-coordinates-from-pdf-map-onto-satellite-image))

Comment: down voters are welcome to explain why they think the question is not well formulated, so I can improve it.

Comment: Some sample data might increase your chances on an good answer (not my downvote btw)..

Answer (score 1):

This operation ("georeferencing") can be done easily in [QGIS](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/georeferencing_basics.html).